# EJB - Dependency Lookup

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0

I am reading a book about EJB and I don't understand the next example:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name="audit", beanInterface=AuditService.class)    
public class DeptServiceBean implements DeptService {
   SessionContext context;
   AuditService audit;

   public void setSessionContext(SessionContext context) {
     this.context = context;
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     audit = (AuditService) context.lookup("audit");
   }
   // ...
}
```

This example is trying to explain "Dependency Lookup". What I don't understand is why is necessary to invoke the lookup method when @EJB annotation has been used. Then, what is @EJB annotation used for?

I expected that the @EJB annotation was enough to get an instance of the AuditService EJB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a little more, I've undestood. The example posted before shows "Dependency look up" (annotation is used at class level). On the other hand exists "Dependency Injection" (annotation is at field level), and in that case, @EJB annotation is enough.